# Android Studio Arctic Fox patch update fails

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, android-studio-arctic-fox

I get a notification in Android Studio about a new patch available. I push the update option and Android Studio does it's thing
[image]

...until the IDE restarts then I get this

[image]

The only option I see at this point is cancel. I've tried this on a few occasions and this happens every time.(obviously)
Is there something I could do to overcome this that isn't as drastic as re-installing Android Studio?

EDIT :

- I've tried running the update with different JDK versions also : File > Project Structure > Gradle Settings > Select a different Gradle JDK.
- The machine is running on Intel architecture.

Further information : The previous install of Android Studio does have the `Contents/plugins/Kotlin` folder, but Arctic Fox does not.

Comment: Is it running on m1 ?

Comment: No, on Intel architecture. I'll add this to the Q. Ta.

Comment: Happens to me everytime on Linux and Mac, I always used to do a clean install
What I now do is use `pacman` and `yay` to update Android Studio on my `ArchLinux` distro and for mac is use `brew` to update it. I mean it's better to let the package managers update it by themselves rather than studio doing it

Comment: Btw, the reason why it happens is because Studio doesn't have permission to edit certain files inside the root directory

Comment: i would suggest you to take your previous project backup ...uninstall full android studio and install it again with new version of studio

Comment: @gtxtreme, are you sure its to do with permissons, the problem seems to be that the files don't exist at all.